Quillen adjunction between Kan and Joyal model structures on sSet
I have read "The thoery of quasi-categories and its application" by A.Joyal. Theorem.6.22 shows that Kan and Joyal model structures on sSet are Quillen adjoint. ($k_! : sSet_{Kan} \to sSet_{Joyal}$ is a left Quillen functor.) He shows $k_!$ preserves weak equivalendce, but I think this proof is not complete.
This shows if $f : X \to Y$ is Kan weak equivalence, then $K_!(f) : k_!(X) \to k_!(Y)$ is also weak equivalence by 2-out-of-3. (since $(-) \to k_!(X)$ are weak equivalnce.) But This only implies $k_!(f)$ is Kan weak equivalence not Joyal weak equivalence!
In general, Kan weak equivalence $f : X \to Y$ are not Joyal weak equiavence. It is (may be) satisfied when $X$ and $Y$ are Kan complexes. So, I ask are $k_!(X)$ and $k_!(Y)$ Kan comlexes? (by fibrant replacement, we can assume $X$ and $Y$ are Kan complexes.)

Note that we cannot simply assume $X$ and $Y$ are Kan complexes, as doing so is assuming that $k_!(X)\to k_!(X')$ is a weak equivalence for any fibrant replacement $X\to X'$ of $X$ $-$but this is already almost the statement we are trying to prove. Also, for a general $X$ it need not be true that $k_!(X)$ is a Kan complex. For instance, $X=\Delta^1\vee\Delta^1$ gives a counterexample, as $k_!(\Delta^1\vee\Delta^1)\cong\Delta'[1]\vee\Delta'[1]$ which does not even have right lifting against $\Lambda^2_1\hookrightarrow\Delta^2$.
As for filling in the gap in the proof: it suffices to show that $k_!$ sends Kan trivial cofibrations to Joyal trivial cofibrations. Since Kan trivial cofibrations are exactly the morphisms that have left lifting against morphisms that themselves have right lifting against the horn inclusions $\Lambda^n_k\hookrightarrow\Delta^n$ for $0\leq k\leq n$ and $n\geq 1$, and since trivial Joyal cofibrations have the left lifting property against morphisms that have right lifting against Joyal trivial cofibrations, general lifting calculus of adjoint functors tells us that it suffices to show that $k_!(\Lambda^n_k)\to k_!(\Delta^n)$ (induced by the inclusion) is a Joyal trivial cofibration. We can glue $\Lambda^n_k$ from $n$ copies of $\Delta^{n-1}$ in a certain way, and this gluing is actually a homotopy colimit (because of Reedy diagram considerations). Likewise, $k_!(\Lambda^n_k)$ is a homotopy colimit (indexed over the same diagram) of $n$ copies of the simplicial sets $k_!(\Delta^{n-1})$ $-$but these are all Joyal contractible. Since the diagram we are taking the homotopy colimit over is weakly contractible itself, we find that $k_!(\Lambda^n_k)$ is Joyal contractible as well, so that our morphism $k_!(\Lambda^n_k)\to k_!(\Delta^n)$ is a cofibration (because $k_!$ preserves those) and a Joyal equivalence (because both sides are contractible). This completes the argument.

Thanks! I am not familar with homotopy colims in sSet, so I cannot understand your proof (preserving trivial cofibrations), but I can do outline of your proof.
Can you fill the gap of "preserving fibration? (joyal does in his book)" ? I understood $k_!(X)$ is not a Kan complex. So how can show this proof? Using fibrant replacement in $sSet_{Joyal}$ ?

Sorry, I don't understand which proof of preserving fibrations you mean. As far as I can see, Joyal does not show that $k_!$ preserves fibrations. Also, you don't have to show that $k^!$ preserves fibrations because it suffices to prove that $k_!$ is left Quillen. Can you clarify what you mean?

Oh, sorry. I wanted to say "preserving weak equivalences."
I maybe understood your proof (preserving trivial cofibrations).
I don't understand Joyal'S proof. He says $k_!(f)$ is acyclic. I think he only shows it is a Kan weak equivlence by 2-out-of-3. But, We need to show $k_!(f)$  is a Joyal weak equivalence. Do I misunderstand his direction of proof?

Preserving weak equivalences follows from preserving trivial cofibrations by Ken Brown's lemma, as any object in the Kan model structure is cofibrant. Note however that in order to show a functor is left Quillen, you don't need to show that it preserves all weak equivalences, only that it preserves cofibrations and trivial cofibrations.

Joyal's proof is insufficient (indeed because Kan trivial cofibrations need not be Joyal trivial cofibrations), and I did not see a quick way to fix it, which is why I gave an alternative proof for the statement that $k_!$ preserves trivial cofibrations.

Thanks. I think about this again.
